# Fileopen through the FolderBrowserDialog.. How?? HELP!

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

This is what i got now...

```
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
 TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Nothing = True Then MsgBox("Select your folder..")
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Nothing = True Then Button1.Enabled = False
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Nothing = False Then Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub

    FileOpen(1, ,,,,,, & "File" & ".dll", OpenMode.Output)
    PrintLine(1, TextBox2.Text)
    FileClose()

End Sub
```

But i want the Output folder (The place where File.dll is saved) to be the FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath... how? Anyone?

Tried FileOpen(1, FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & File & .dll, OpenMode.Output) but no :(

Answer (score 0):

Note sure I understand what you want to do, but you may try to set the SelectedPath property before calling ShowDialog method.